# Adding movie clips with for loop action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3

Hey wondering if anybody can help me, i am trying to add a load of move clips and make them clickable to the stage in action script 3,i can work out the spacing of them later i just keep getting errors while trying to add them using this :

```
for(var x:int = 1; x <= 10; x++)
        {

            var this["cardPrint"+x] :MovieClip = new this["card_"+x]();
            this.addChild(this["cardPrint"+x]);
            this["cardPrint"+x].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this["click_"+x]);

        }
```

a point in the right direction would help alot
thank you

Comment: does your "cardPrint" movieclip already exist in the libary - are you trying to create instances of that?

Comment: i am trying to create instances of the "cardPrint"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` is a scope indicator that indicates the current class. So `this["cardPrint"+x]` is actually trying to find a variable with that name, but you can't declare a variable that is already a reference.

The only way to do what you want is like this:

```
public dynamic class Foobar 
{
    public function Foobar() 
    {
        for(var x:int = 1; x <= 10; x++)
        {
            this["cardPrint"+x] = new this["card_"+x]();
            this.addChild(this["cardPrint"+x]);
            this["cardPrint"+x].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this["click_"+x]);
        }
    }
}
```

The key is making the class `dynamic`. That allows you to create variable names at run time and to create them in string form using the `scope["varName"]` syntax. If you are doing this on the timeline in Flash Pro, as I get the feeling you are, this is simply not possible the way you want to do it. You would be better off creating objects in the loop and storing them in an array to access them that way instead of using the syntax described above.

The datatype of each object created will be the same as whatever is instantiated, so you won't be able to set it to be `MovieClip` or similar.

`"card_"+x` also needs to be an instantiable object (a `Class`). If it is not, you cannot instantiate it and it will always error out.

I do want to caution you that is a very poor way of putting this together. The room for error is incredibly large and using this syntax will be difficult to do and difficult to read in your code.

Comment: Thank you i will go back to the drawing board and begin again, i am just starting out with as3, thank you again

Comment: No problem. I would highly recommend attempting to store each object in an array (or even a generic `Object`) instead of doing it this way. Generally, using the `this["varName"]` syntax is used for retrieving, not setting. Obviously there are exceptions, but what you are trying to do is generally best dealt with through Arrays/Vectors.

Comment: thank you again, thats what i am currently attempting to do, i am just starting out, thank you so much